# Как можно сделать ссылку в модуле fs в nodeJS чтобы ссылаться на файл из другой дирректории

Tags: node.js

У меня вопрос, как можно реализовать вот такую штуку.

мне нужно, чтобы модуль **fs** в **nodejs** при создании **filepath** ссылался на другую директорию.

У меня файл **index.js** лежит в одной подпапке, а **index.html** в другой.
А у меня получается, что у меня получается вот такой полный путь при запуске сервера- `D:\...\NodeJS\HTML\index.html` , но у меня папка HTML не лежит в папке NodeJS!
Она отдельная.

```js
let = filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'HTML', req.url === '/' ? 'index.html' : req.url)

fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'HTML', 'error.html'), (err, data) => {
```

Помогите, пожалуйста. Надеюсь вы поняли, что я написал :)

Comment: `path.join(__dirname, '..', 'HTML'`

Comment: Спасибо! это работает! Но в процессе появились еще проблемы. Мне нужно, чтобы в этом методе с помощью switch case nodejs сам определял какой это файл (css, js и т.д), но при этом у меня сформированы все файлы по папкам. .html в папке HTML, .css в папке CSS и т.д. когда я запускаю программу, у меня все равно идет через папку HTML все файлы. как мне можно сгруппировать в java script все это по папкам, и чтобы оно самоопределялось, какой файл (css, html и т.д)

Comment: ссылка не работает

Comment: Ссылка работает, но там нет ничего по моей проблеме. Мне нужно, чтобы другие папки (по типу HTML) не входили в папку NodeJS. а то у меня получается, что мой файл находится по такой директории - D:\...\HTMl\CSS\main.css, а должен быть сразу - D:\...\CSS\main.css. проблема в том, что папка залезает в папку, где файла конечно же нет.

Comment: Вот так НЕ должно быть - D:\...\HTMl\CSS\main.css   .   Вот так должно быть - D:\...\CSS\main.css .  а иначе у меня нет подпапки  CSS в папке HTML...

Comment: https://pastebin.com/5JgvVkkw

Comment: Огромное Спасибо!!! Благодарствую!